# Handling Keyboard events WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, event-handling

In my WPF MVVM application, I am subscribing to `PreviewKeyUp` and `PreviewKeyDown` in `UserControl1.xaml.cs` as such:

```
UserControl1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var window = Window.GetWindow(this);
    window.PreviewKeyUp += UserControl1_PreviewKeyUp;
    window.PreviewKeyDown += UserControl1_PreviewKeyDown;
}
```

Should I worry about a memory leak? Do I have to unsubscribe from these events in the `Unloaded` event or will the GC take care of it?

Comment: It is a good practice to unsubscribe the event when the controller is unloaded. (Eg: this.Unloaded event). But as per my understanding GC will do those things automatically when the form/ controller is unloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I worry about a memory leak?

Only if the parent window that publish the events lives longer than the `UserControl` that subscribes to the event.

> Do I have to unsubscribe from these events in the Unloaded event or will the GC take care of it?

You need to unexplicitly unsubscribe for the window not to keep the `UserControl` instance alive. Again, this is not an issue if the both the window and the `UserControl` become eligible for garbage collection at the same time.

The garbage collector never unsubscribe from any events for you though.